# SDL_LoadBMP fails intermittently

Tags: sdl

I am calling SDL_LoadBMP("duck.bmp") in a loop ten thousand times.

After about the thousandth time, the call fails and SDL_GetError() reports:

"Couldn't open duck.bmp"

I can't figure out why this is -- is there anything I can do to get more information?

It sounds like perhaps it may be a memory issue, but there is plenty of system RAM free when this occurs.

Note: the BMP is 32x32.

Comment: OS?  If win32/64, do you have a virus scanner with "on access"-type scanning running?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have plenty of free system RAM, could still run out of address space; you generally only get 2GB to work with in a 32-bit application.  Although with an image that tiny, it ought to take way more than 1000 times to use up that much memory.  Are you doing anything else memory-hungry in your loop?

Most importantly, is there a reason you want to re-load the image file 10,000 times?  If you're looking for multiple copies of the image to manipulate, I'd recommend making copies of the original surface with [SDL_ConvertSurface](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_ConvertSurface) instead of going back to the file each time.  If this method fails as well, it's possible that SDL_GetError will give you a more meaningful error message when it does.

If you are also writing data back to that file, make sure you're properly closing it, or you might be running into a permissions sort of issue.  I'm pretty sure that Windows won't allow you to open a file for reading that is already open for writing.  (This seems less likely since you're only hitting the problem after a thousand iterations of your loop, but it's worth checking.)

Answer (score 1):

When you're done with the image, you should call SDL_FreeSurface (see http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FreeSurface).  Otherwise, well, the memory is not freed.

As Raptor007 points out, loading an image 1000 times is, ahem, not recommended.  I assumed you were doing this to see if there was a memory leak.  If not... stop doing it.  Once is enough.